# Is there any way of creating a component with images based on user input?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to let the user input a image that i later can display in another component, It is supposed to be displayed inside my "Card" component which is displayed inside my "Grid" component. The grid component then maps and displays all the houses in the "houses" array which also is a separate component. Manually creating houses inside the array works perfectly but when the user is trying to add a house everything but the images works. The console log in submitListing will show that the houses beeing added does contain an image but it is not beeing displayed in the grid. (Also, the first house that is submitted only contains an empty array for mainImg but the rest contains the "blob" image) Entire project: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-orla-fqcwoy?file=/src/components/header/AddListing.jsx

HTML

```
<textarea
  value={listing.area}
  name="area"
  onChange={handleChange}
  className="area"
></textarea>


<input
  onChange={handleInputChange}
  name="mainImg"
  type={"file"}
></input>
```

JS

```
const [listing, setListing] = useState({
    area: "",
    mainImg: [],
  });

function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setListing((previousListing) => {
      return { ...previousListing, [name]: value };
    });
  }
const [file, setFile] = useState();

function handleInputChange(e) {
  setFile(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
}

function submitListing(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  setListing({
    area: "",
    mainImg: file,
  });
  houses.push(listing);
  console.log(houses);
}
```

Comment: whats the issue here, you have done pretty much right. you just need to create an `<img>` element with `src` = 'url returned by `URL.createObjectURL`'

Comment: The problem is that i dont want the "file" which is returned by URL.createObjectUrl to be displayed in the same component, if i add an <img src={file} /> the image is displayed but from the wrong component, I want to store the "file" inside of my houses array, which it does but when i try to render the specific house inside of my "Grid" component. The text from "area" is displayed but not "mainImg".

Comment: Honestly for me it is hard to understand how to help, if you can provide more info about your data flows and components, like i have this component, this, this, here is a code, or even better - here is a js fiddle or codensandbox - we would be able to answer. We dont see all the picture. What mistake i see - `setListing` before `houses.push(listing)` - setListing does not update listing immediately, it will be updated on next render only. Do `const newListing = {...}; setListing(newListing); houses.push(newListing);`

Comment: Okay, I have uploaded the entire program to codesandbox, I'm sorry for the bad information I just started web developement 3 weeks ago and this is my first project without a tutorial. I know it might be a bit overwhelming with the entire project but the relevant components would be: AddListing, Card, Grid and houses. Also this way you can test it out for yourself by submitting a listing. If you ever feel like you have the time please take a look, Thank you. https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-orla-fqcwoy?file=/src/components/header/AddListing.jsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here are the issues. I might forget something but i forked codesandbox, so you will be able to compare.

1. In your houses.js and AddListing.jsx you had `mainImage` and `mainImg`. You need to have a strict structure and naming, they had to match.
2. `const [file, setFile]` was.. useless, you had to save blobs into the `listing` object itself in the `mainImage`, `img2`, etc.
3. About the structure again. You had your `mainImg`, `img2`, ... set to an empty array, []. That have no sense due to you dont use `<input type="file" multiple>`. Switched them to undefined / string.
4. You cannot really bind `value` to the `input type=file` in react. Just remove the value from inputs.
5. Be careful with useEffects and useState's setValues, without understanding how they work it is really easy to make a mistake.

Here is your updated and working AddListing.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import "./AddListing.css";
import houses from "../../houses";

const getDefaultListing = () => {
  return {
    id: houses.length + 1,
    area: "",
    state: "",
    shortDesc: "",
    longDesc: "",
    pricePerNight: "",
    cleaningFee: "",
    serviceFee: "",
    mainImage: undefined,
    img2: undefined,
    img3: undefined,
    img4: undefined,
    img5: undefined
  };
};

function AddListing() {
  const [listing, setListing] = useState(() => getDefaultListing());

  const handleChange = useCallback((e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setListing((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
  }, []);

  const handleInputChange = useCallback((e) => {
    const { name, files } = e.target;
    const [singleImage] = files;
    if (!singleImage) {
      setListing((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: undefined }));
    } else {
      const blob = URL.createObjectURL(singleImage);
      setListing((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: blob }));
    }
  }, []);

  const submitListing = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      houses.push(listing);
      setListing(() => getDefaultListing());
      console.log(houses);
    },
    [listing]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(listing);
  }, [listing]);

  return (
    <div className="add-listing-div">
      <form>
        <p id="p1">State</p>
        <p id="p2">Area</p>
        <textarea
          value={listing.state}
          name="state"
          onChange={handleChange}
          className="state"
        />
        <textarea
          value={listing.area}
          name="area"
          onChange={handleChange}
          className="area"
        />
        <p id="p3">Short Description</p>
        <textarea
          value={listing.shortDesc}
          name="shortDesc"
          onChange={handleChange}
          className="short-description"
        />
        <p id="p4">Long Description</p>
        <textarea
          value={listing.longDesc}
          name="longDesc"
          onChange={handleChange}
          className="long-description"
        />
        <p id="p5">Price/Night</p>
        <p id="p6">Cleaning Fee</p>
        <p id="p7">Service Fee</p>
        <textarea
          value={listing.pricePerNight}
          name="pricePerNight"
          onChange={handleChange}
          className="price-per-night"
        />
        <textarea
          value={listing.cleaningFee}
          name="cleaningFee"
          onChange={handleChange}
          className="cleaning-fee"
        />
        <textarea
          value={listing.serviceFee}
          name="serviceFee"
          onChange={handleChange}
          className="service-fee"
        />
        <label>Main Image: </label>
        <input onChange={handleInputChange} name="mainImage" type="file" />
        <label>Second Image: </label>
        <input onChange={handleInputChange} name="img2" type="file" />
        <label>Third Image: </label>
        <input onChange={handleInputChange} name="img3" type="file" />
        <label>Fourth Image: </label>
        <input onChange={handleInputChange} name="img4" type="file" />
        <label>Fifth Image: </label>
        <input onChange={handleInputChange} name="img5" type="file" />
        <button onClick={submitListing}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddListing;
```

[image: Edit React modal with files]

Comment: okay, thank you very much both for the help and the tips. I will have it in mind in the future! :D